# Op-Amp integrator with offset voltage output time function

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrator, input-offset-voltage

I am studying the function of an Op-Amp integrator with offset voltage that is in the picture below: [image: Op-Amp integrator with offset voltage]

I have derived the output voltage formula myself, but I am not sure if it is correct. The formula is given below:
$$V_o = {V_{off}\over{RC}} - {1\over{RC}}\int_0^tV_{in}dt$$

Can anybody please tell me if the formula is correct or not? I have searched the literature and the internet, but I couldn't find the answer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if we assume an ideal opamp we know that the current trough \$\text{R}\$ must be the same current trough \$\text{C}\$. So we can write:

$$\text{i}_\text{R}\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{i}_\text{C}\left(\text{s}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\frac{\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{v}_-\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{R}}=\frac{\text{v}_-\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}\tag1$$

We also know that the ideal opamp wants to establish \$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-\$. And in your circuit we know that \$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_\text{off}\$. So using this, we can rewrite \$(1)\$ as follows:

$$\frac{\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{v}_\text{off}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{R}}=\frac{\text{v}_\text{off}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{v}_\text{off}\left(\text{s}\right)-\frac{\text{v}_\text{in}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{v}_\text{off}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{sCR}}\tag2$$

Which is not hard to transform back to the time domain. I let you do that.

Comment: *We also know that the ideal opamp wants to establish \$V_+=V_ −\$.* This is only the case for a negative feedback configuration. If there was positive feedback instead this would not hold.

Answer (score 1):

No, the integral should contain (VIN-Voff)

Answer (score 0):

The node equation for \$V_-\$ is
$$\frac{V_--V_\text{in}}{R}+C\frac{\text{d}(V_--V_\text{o})}{\text{d}t} =0$$
Due to the negative feedback of the op-amp configuration, the principle of a **virtual short** can be applied, meaning that \$V_+=V_- \Rightarrow V_-=V_\text{off}\$

Substituting gives you
$$\frac{V_\text{off}-V_\text{in}}{R}+C\frac{\text{d}(V_\text{off}-V_\text{o})}{\text{d}t} =0 $$
Can you do the rest?

Comment: Thank you for your time and help jp314 and Carl. I managed to do the rest.  The correct formula is given below (posted in case somebody runs into the same problem): 

$$Vo = V_off+{1\over{RC}}\int_0^t(V_{off}-Vin)dt$$

Comment: @NikolaRistic Good work! You could (and should, for the record) accept an answer to show others that the question-and-*answer* of this post has been achieved. Whether you write your own answer and accept that, or accept mine or jp314 is up to you.